# Add divs with classes with image inside with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write some JS so that the end result adds this to the HTML.  I plan to have an array of images to index through and populate the page with images.  Is there a simple way of doing this? Will I need to switch the classes to IDs for each image?

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/480x480"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have figured out how to add a div with a class.

```
var newInner = document.createElement('div');
newInner.className = 'boxInner';
document.getElementById("wrap").appendChild(newInner);
```

I also figured out how to append an image. I am stuck trying to put all of these together.

```
var newImage = document.createElement("img");
newImage.setAttribute("src", "http://placehold.it/480x480");
document.getElementById("wrap").appendChild(newImage);
```

Comment: `newInner.appendChild(newImage);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an array with the img srcs and a div with the id of 'box':

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var newInner = document.createElement('div');
    newInner.className = 'boxInner';
    var newImage = document.createElement('img');
    newImage.setAttribute('src', imgs[i]);
    newInner.appendChild(newImage);
    box.appendChild(newInner);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it.

```js
var images = ["http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg", "http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg", "http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg", "http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg"];

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
  imgElement.src = images[i];
  container.appendChild(imgElement);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```